# Where should I write queries in model or controller (sequelize)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I try to figure out where should I write queries in node js application which uses [sequalize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) as an ORM.

For example, I have a model address, and I write data to like this:

```
let adr = await Address.create({street, number, city, state, country})
```

Should I write this code in the controller where I get the data or in the model and then just pass (for example full object address) to the method of the model? What is the best practice?

I assume that is it better to write it in models because I can use the same code in many controllers. But maybe there are some other constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you should use a `repository`. The ideea behind is to make a module that will abstract the database, just inject it in as a dependency, and then use the repository in controller a short example can be like this.

```
// repository.js

module.exports = (db) => {
   const findUserById = (id) => {
        // db query your user by id
   }

   const createUser = (data) {
       // db insert a new user
   }

   // ... other repository functions to deal with the database

   return Object.create({
     findUserById,
     createUser,
     // ...
   })
}
```

And then in your controller you will just use the repository by giving the proper db connection.

```
const repository = require('./repository.js')(dbConnection);

app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
   repository.findUserById(req.params.id);
   // ...
})
```

And in this way you can easily test your code by mocking the database or even test with good values. And you abstract your db connection and other important features when for example you will need to change your database from `mysql` to `mongodb` you will change only the repository not the entire application or controllers.

So a good practice is to use the repository for `sequelize` there also exist a way to do it.

```
var db = require('../models');

var UsersRepository = {
    findByEmail: function(email) {
        return db.User.findAll({
            where: {
                email: email
            }
        })
    }
}

module.exports = UsersRepository;
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to have one repository per model or one per whole application?

Comment: each model with his repository

Comment: In this way you will not have 2000 lines files, and is more structured

Comment: That sound reasonable. In this case, what should I put into the model except for data schema and hooks?

Comment: Model related function, and business logic, lets abstract in this way, if it is related with database put in repository, if it is related with the object instance put in the model.

Comment: Is there exist standard folder name for repositories? For example, I keep models in "models" folder and controllers in "controllers" folder.

Comment: I personally use `/repository/user-repository.js`

Comment: I'm I understand right that in controllers you use repositories and in repositories you use models?

Comment: But the question was where to define a custom query?

Comment: @RameshPareek Custome queries you define in the repositories

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru  I got type error which will you please take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181926/node-js-sequelize-repository-pattern-node2944-unhandledpromiserejectionwarnin